# How to open a native iOS app from Foursquare /checkins/reply?

Tags: api, foursquare

I am using Foursquare's checkins/reply API endpoint https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/reply.

I would like the reply to open a native app https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/client#appintegration

However if the url param of the call to checkins/reply includes our iOS app protocol (like ourapp://) it causes an error because (seemingly) it's not one of http://, https://, foursquare://, mailto://, tel:// or sms://.

I've tried many variations of contentId, this nasty thing: fsq+LC_CLIENT_ID+ACTION_TYPE:// and others without positive results.

Has anyone been able to open a native iOS app from a Foursquare checkins reply?

Answer (score 0):

On [this page](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/reply), you'll be able to find the documentation for the `contentId` parameter in your checkins/reply request.

[This page](https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/client#appintegration) indicates how the `contentId` is used to register a `fsq+CLIENT_ID+reply://` link.

You will need to register the proper URL in your apps .plist configuration in order for the links to work.

Comment: Android related: I've tried setting my URL in the response to the aforementioned fsq+CLIENT_ID+reply:// but Foursquare only supports "http, https, foursquare, mailto, tel, and sms" url schemes, which I understand. 

What I don't understand is how my url let's say: https://myapp.appspot.com/reply gets turned into a scheme: fsq+CLIENT_ID+reply:// link that my app is supposed to intercept before showing the in-app browser. I've added the following handlers to my intent-filters, I still have to click the (external) "browser" button to get to my app. https://gist.github.com/thunsaker/6359938